# Moxy: How pass params to Presenter?

Tags: android, android-moxy

Here my implementation of MVP:

```
public class OfferDetailsPdfActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnPageChangeListener, OfferDetailsPdfMvp.View {
  private PdfPresenterImpl presenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int offerId = 0;
        if (extras != null) {
            offerId = extras.getInt(Offer.ID);
        }
        presenter = PdfPresenterImpl.getInstance(this, offerId);
}
```

Now I want to use **Moxy**.

So here change on Activity

```
public class OfferDetailsPdfActivity extends MvpAppCompatActivity implements OnPageChangeListener, OfferDetailsPdfMvp.View {
    @InjectPresenter
    PdfPresenterImpl presenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int offerId = 0;
        if (extras != null) {
            offerId = extras.getInt(Offer.ID);
    }
        // how pass parameter to presenter?
       // presenter = PdfPresenterImpl.getInstance(this, offerId);
}
```

But now how I can pass params `(context, offerId)` to Presenter?

Answer (score 6):

Moxy has special annotation `@ProvidePreseter` for make Presenter by custom constructor. There is more [info](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy/wiki/Provides-Presenter-and-its-Tag) and [example](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy/blob/develop/sample-github/src/main/java/com/arellomobile/mvp/sample/github/ui/fragments/DetailsFragment.java#L48). Also, I strongly recommended to not pass context to presenter. Because then context may leak.

Answer (score 1):

`@ProvidePresenter` should do the trick. Check out the example: 
https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy/wiki/Custom-Presenter-constuructor